# Prolog - adding two arguments, even if one is not a number

Tags: prolog

in Prolog, how should I proceed when I want to add two arguments, even if one is not a number. So for instance, if I enter `add2args(1,2,R).` the result should be `R = 3`. If I enter `add2args(1,x,R).` the result should be `R=1+x`.

So far I have this:

```
add_2args(X,Y,R):- number(X),number(Y), R is (X+Y).
```

Which allows me to add two numbers, but I don't know how I can get it to print out anything other than true and false if `X` and `Y` are not numbers which is normal since `number(X)` checks if `X` is a number or not. What other rule do I have to add to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prolog will view an expression symbolically (as a Prolog term) unless explicitly evaluated with something like `is/2`. So the simplest way to do this in your case would be the following:

```
add_2args(X, Y, R) :-
    (   number(X), number(Y)  % Both X and Y are numbers, then...
    ->  R is X + Y            % Evaluate the expression
    ;   R = X + Y             % Else, just unify R with the expression
    ).
```

The `R = X + Y` will not evaluate the expression but only unify the term `X + Y` with `R`. This is also a nice "Prolog beginner's guide" illustration for the difference between `=/2` and `is/2`. If you wrote, for example, `R = 2 + 3`, then did a `write(R)` you would see `2 + 3`, not `5`. You could subsequently do, `Result is R` which would then evaluate the expression `R` and yield `Result = 5`.

```
| ?- R = 2 + 3, Result is R.

R = 2+3
Result = 5

yes
| ?-
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation

Comment: @Streamline if I answered your question, you can accept the answer by clicking the big check mark on the left. :)

Comment: Done! Thanks again :)